# .png icons are not displaying after upgrading to Domino V10 FP4

Tags: xpages

We have XPages applications which uses .png icons displays on web pages. .png files are stored in File Resources in NSF.
After upgrading from Domino 9.0.1 FP10 to Domino 10 FP4, .png files are not displayed on the web pages.
Any quick fix for this?

Comment: What HTTP response code does Domino return for the png images?

Comment: We are using IE 11. Response code is 200 ok, but the icons shows cross icon instead of original icon.

Comment: Are you able to open the png directly in a new tab, or in a real browser ?

Comment: Did you rebuild / clean your xpage?

Comment: tried clean build, but .png not displayed. file not displayed if opened directly in browser (.png file complete URL). .gif file has no issue.

Comment: Sounds like a case for support. Just for fun: would it work in Firefox or when you use curl to pull the image?

Comment: Google Chrome is showing icons correctly. But IE fails. Tried using all Document Modes in IE, User Agent in F12, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue but with CSS. Make sure image in your database under Web Properties has mime type set to image/png

Ours was set to image/jpeg

Comment: Thank you. That worked. We had .png files under Images, where mime type property was disabled. We moved these files to "Files", where mime type was auto set to image/png and it started displaying on web.